# Find list of elements leading up to selected element in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an array of every element that leads up to, for example, a clicked piece of text in jquery.

Say I have this html:

```
<div class='foo'>
<div class='bar'>
<span id='42'><h1>Hey there!</h1></span
</div>
</div>
```

When I click on "Hey there!" I want:

```
<div class='foo'>
<div class='bar'>
<span id='42'><h1>
```

stored in, say, an array, but I do NOT want the text value I clicked on nor anything that comes after. I've been exploring various options but i'm having trouble coming up with anything.

Comment: Please explain what you want to do with that sort of HTML in an array. You usecase isn't clear enough. Typically it could be useful to store all the class and id parameter values of all the parent elements but why the HTML? Is it really the whole HTML that you want stored? If that's so, why an array?

Comment: @Unrealist It's not necessarily the entire html structure that I need to store, but I do need to know that there are, for example, 3 divs before the text i've clicked on, and they have 'foo', 'bar', and 'soap' classes respectively. I'm doing some scraping, and trying to pull out data from a page.

Comment: Just create a click handler that recursively checks the parent element to see if one exists, this should give you the element hierarchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following registers a click handler that logs information about the ancestor elements every time something is clicked on the page:

```
$('body').on('click', function (event) { 
    var info = $($(event.target).parents().get().reverse()).map(function () { 
        var $this = $(this);
        return { 
            node: this.nodeName, 
            id: this.id, 
            className: $this.attr('class') 
        }; 
    }).get();
    console.log(info);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try utilizing a combination of .parent() and .index() to solve this issue.
Obviously if performance is a concern, I wouldn't suggest this approach.

```
var el = $('#42');
var parent = el.parent();
parent.index(el); // 4
```

Then you can check the elements prior.